# Check if user has access to the backend

Tags: authentication

I have searched through forum and couldn't find answer to simple thing that I am trying to accompish

I created a new group under "Public" group and I provided that user a permission of "Administrator Login" in global configuration. User can login fine in Admin panel but In one of my system plugin, I want to check if the user has access to the backend. How can I accomplish that?

I tried following:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$isroot = $user->authorise('core.admin');
```

but looks like that only detects if user is a super admin. My user with a special group permission by no means is a super user.

I will apreciate if someone can guide me in a right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backend `com_login` component `LoginController` checks for `core.login.admin` permission. This is exactly the one you edited - `Administrator Login`.

So, change permission you are checking and you are good to go:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$isroot = $user->authorise('core.login.admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through the Joomla group ID.

To find the Joomla group ID, go to `Users -> Groups` and check the last column.

Once you have the group ID, you can use this code or similar:

```
<?php
  //Get Group Memberships
  $user = JFactory::getUser();
  $groups = $user->get('groups');
  foreach($groups as $groupid) {
    if ($groupid == "8") $superadmin = "Yes";
    if ($groupid == "7") $admin = "Yes";
    if ($groupid == "2") $registered = "Yes";
  }
?>
```